# How do I use the ruby ffi gem to call a freestanding function in a rust library?

Tags: ruby, rust, ffi, ruby-ffi

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
rustc 0.13.0-nightly (f168c12c5 2014-10-25 20:57:10 +0000)
```

I want to use the `ffi` gem in conjunction with `rust`.

I have read [this](http://brson.github.io/2013/03/10/embedding-rust-in-ruby/) (quite outdated) blog post, which shows how to do that.

The problem is: it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

test.rs:

```
fn test(bla: i32) -> i32 { bla*bla }

#[no_mangle]
extern fn _test_wrapper(i: i32) -> i32 {
  test(i)
}
```

test.rb:

```
require 'ffi'

module Test
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib File.absolute_path 'libtest.so'

  attach_function :_test_wrapper, [:int32], :int32
end
```

I compile test.rs like so:

```
rustc --crate-type dylib test.rs
```

And then

```
ruby test.rb
```

Output:

```
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/ffi-1.9.6/lib/ffi/library.rb:261:in `attach_function': Function '_test_wrapper' not found in [/home/me/Dokumente/ruby/rust_require/specs/test/libtest.so] (FFI::NotFoundError)
    from test.rb:7:in `<module:Test>'
    from test.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

What do I do wrong? (I already tried making it `pub extern fn` ..., doesn't work either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, you just need to fix the warning you get when you compile the Rust code and make the function public:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn _test_wrapper(i: i32) -> i32 {
  test(i)
}
```

To help me debug the problem, I used `nm` to see what symbols the compiled library exports. I'm on OS X, so you might have to tweak arguments and filenames:

```
$ nm -g libtest.dylib
0000000000000e30 T __test_wrapper
0000000000001020 S _rust_metadata_test_04c178c971a6f904
                 U _rust_stack_exhausted
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Before marking the function as public, it did not show up in this list.

Comment: thank you for looking into this! unfortunately this doesn't work for me..

my ```nm``` output: [link](https://gist.github.com/flo-l/df5a0b8c5f63772b0c7d)

Comment: For what it's worth, I created a fresh Ubuntu install, installed rustc 0.13.0-nightly (ceeac26de 2014-11-04 21:26:23 +0000), installed ruby 2.1.3p242, and ffi (1.9.6). I added `pub` and tweaked the Ruby code to print stuff and it worked just fine.

Comment: I also reinstalled everything and now it works! thank you for heroic effort!!

Comment: That `nm` tool is amazing! I was able to discover that my `no_mangle` annotation was not in the right place, leading to mangled function names in the lib.